# How to fix the intellisense on a custom HtmlHelper Extension?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, razor, intellisense, html-helper

Using VB.NET with MVC3 and Razor.

I have a test page for a custom extension to **htmlhelper**. Visual Studio tells me the view is not ok :

### code of index.vbhtml (view)

```
<h2>@ViewData("Message")</h2>

@Html.CustomLink("text 321312", 123)
```

**Error** : CustomLink is not a member of System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper(..)

### code of LinkExtension.vb (extension)

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Web.Mvc

Public Module htmlHelperExtensions
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function CustomLink(htmlHelper As HtmlHelper, linkText As String, uuid As Short) As MvcHtmlString
        Return MvcHtmlString.Create(String.Format("<a href="#{1}">{0}</a>", linkText, uuid )
    End Function
End Module
```

### web.config (added namespace)

I added a reference to my librairy in both general web.config and view web.config
(I also tried to add it to the controller.)

```
<system.web>
  <pages>
    <namespaces>
      [...]
      <add namespace="linkExtension" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web>
```

**The page run correctly and build the html as I need it**. But VS keeps telling me the code is not right (*CustomLink is not a member of 'System.Web.HtmlHelper(Of Object)'*)! Any ideas?

Comment: Sometimes after adding a namespace to the web.config file in the Views folder, it is necessary to unload the project, and reload it to get Intellisense for a new helper class.

Comment: I added the namespace to the web.config in the view folder, but it still give me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the project when adding the namespace:

```
<add namespace="MyProject.linkExtension" />
```

If you're unsure what it is, locate the project where your `htmlHelperExtensions` is, right-click it in the Solution Explorer, select *Properties*, and on the *Application* tab use the value under the *"Root namespace"* label.

Also, your code doesn't show the usage of `Namespace linkExtension` defined in the extension file, so if the above doesn't work try adding it to your module:

```
Namespace linkExtension
    Public Module htmlHelperExtensions
        <Extension()> _
        Public Function CustomLink(htmlHelper As HtmlHelper, linkText As String, uuid As Short) As MvcHtmlString
            Return MvcHtmlString.Create(String.Format("<a href="#{1}">{0}</a>", linkText, uuid )
        End Function
    End Module
End Namespace
```

If that doesn't help then what version of MVC are you running on? A [similar issue was reported](http://forums.asp.net/t/1694828.aspx/1) by someone also using VB.NET. In that person's case they got it working when upgrading all their projects to MVC 3, or uninstalling MVC 3 since they were using MVC 2. Apparently there was also some interference with having SP1 and Azure Tools installed.

Comment: linkExtension is my root project name, which is why there's no namespace defined. linkExtension.linkExtension would sorta be redundant. I tried adding a namespace : didn't change a thing (still works, still tell it's not right). The project is based on [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-vb), which is MVC3 (need/use Razor). Not sure about SP1 (got it) and Azure Tools (not installed).

Comment: Well, it seems that my library was using the MVC2 dll instead of the MVC3 one. Now, it works nicely.